# What is the meaning of the is_autogenerated field for category url_rewrites?

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

I am investigating an issue where a category has more than one url rewrites. It looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from url_rewrite where entity_id = 8597 and entity_type = 'category';
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+------------------+----------+
| url_rewrite_id | entity_type | entity_id | request_path                      | target_path                   | redirect_type | store_id | description | is_autogenerated | metadata |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+------------------+----------+
|         395619 | category    |      8597 | food/yummy/bananas.html           | catalog/category/view/id/8597 |             0 |        2 | NULL        |                1 | NULL     |
|         404017 | category    |      8597 | product/food/bananas.html         | catalog/category/view/id/8597 |             0 |        2 | NULL        |                0 | NULL     |
|         404025 | category    |      8597 | food/good-bananas.html            | catalog/category/view/id/8597 |             0 |        2 | NULL        |                0 | NULL     |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

The value in the "URL Rewrite" field on the category detail page in Magento Admin matches the value in the *autogenerated* row.

I wonder what the values 0/1 of *is_autogenerated* mean. How exactly would I create a "non-autogenerated" url rewrite for a category in Magento2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url_rewrite` table includes **all rewrites**, including products and rewrites that you created from the admin.

You can create manual rewrites for categories or products from the admin[image] so that's why you have that `0` or  `1` for categories as well.

See from the admin under `Marketing => Seo & Search => Url rewrites`

Comment: Does that mean, that the value for "autogenerated" *is always 0* for entity_type `category`? And we just have a data issue, if I get the above result from this sql statement?

Comment: Answer corrected and updated, sorry for confusion